# How do I change all the locations of multiple objects in multiple key-frames by the same amount when duplicated?

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes

I have an animation with 13 different objects at around 0,0,0. They each have 9 key-frames. I want to duplicate it 40m above it (0,0,40) so that there is another exact same animation playing 40m above it. When I do that, It adds 40m to all the z location of objects, but not the z location of the key-frames. So, when I start the animation, the duplicated objects teleports back to 0,0,0 as the key-frames locations are not changed. How do I fix that? Is it possible to also add the z location inside the key-frames when the object is duplicated just like it does to the z location to the object's original location? Or is it possible to add all the key-frames z locations by the same amount (40m)? I tried changing every key-frames, but it takes forever, as there are 117 of them, which I have to calculate the sum of 40 for each of them for a long time (There are decimals and negative values of locations too).

Comment: There could be 3 ways to do this. The easiest possibly is to give each object it's own parent (a sort of navigation handle) and move the parent up to where it has to go.  The object and it's animation will follow.

Comment: PS: to the above - so long as they're not linked to any other that is.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just a beginner to this, and this really saved my day on a school project. (My friends used paint to animate it so they got no help.)

Comment: Good to hear that!  :)